# HIVE VIEW ERROR

Tags: hadoop, hive

i am new to hadoop hive, i tried to create a one on one  hive view over a hive table but i get an unknown host exception :(

1. given below is the DDL for the table :

   ```
   CREATE TABLE CLIAMS (
   CLAIM_KEY INT,
   CLAIM_NAME STRING
   )STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE;
   ```
2. GIVEN BELOW IS THE VIEW DEFINITION:

   ```
   create view claimant_view as select * from claims;
   ```
3. when i so a select from the view i get following exception thrown:

   ```
   select * from claimant_view;
   Total MapReduce jobs = 1
   Launching Job 1 out of 1
   Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
   WARNING: org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.EventCounter is deprecated. Please use org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter in all the log4j.properties files.
   Execution log at: /tmp/root/root_20130128022828_021334d7-cd4e-4499-b053-d239b7b839ee.log
   java.net.UnknownHostException: server-1358839685-az-1-region-a-geo-1.localdomain: server-1358839685-az-1-region-a-geo-1.localdomain
           at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1360)
           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:920)
           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:896)
           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:896)
           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:870)
           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:435)
           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:677)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
   Job Submission failed with exception 'java.net.UnknownHostException(server-1358839685-az-1-region-a-geo-1.localdomain: server-1358839685-az-1-region-a-geo-1.localdomain)'
   Execution failed with exit status: 1
   Obtaining error information

   Task failed!
   Task ID:
     Stage-1
   ```

Logs:

```
/tmp/root/hive.log
```

someone kindly help me understand the issue and please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Is your Table named "CLAIMS" or "CLIAMS"?  If your table is actually named "CLIAMS", then your Create View did not work.   And, are you running these statements in the same session ands therefore the same database?  You could try "show database" to determine where your current session is running.  Then, run your query as

  "select * from {my database}.claimant_view"